# How does Shape Splitter on Glass Work?

Tags: android, camera, swipe, google-glass, interaction

I want to create a Glass app that responds to a finger waved past the Glass camera much like the shape splitter mini game does.  For those of you who are unfamiliar with shape splitter a screen cast to a phone of it is shown here, the swiping is created by moving your finger in front of glass' camera. http://youtu.be/aKGgT8H0AJM?t=4m27s

I'm curious as to how this works and how I can use my hand as an interactive part of my application.  Does anyone know how this is done?  Or have any suggestions for recreating the same effect?